# Type-safe access only specific array-typed parameters of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I would like to access a set of the properties of my object which I know are all arrays. How do I achieve this please?

```js
interface FilterItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
interface OrganizationFilterItem extends FilterItem {
  organizationTypeId: number;
}
interface Filter {
  serviceProviderId: number;
  farmIds: number[];
  organizationIds: number[];
  userId: number;
  possibleFields: FilterItem[];
  possibleFarms: FilterItem[];
  cropTypeIds: number[];
  planIds: number[];
  possibleOrganizations: OrganizationFilterItem[];
  possibleCropTypes: FilterItem[];
  possiblePlans: FilterItem[];
  fieldIds: number[];
  [key: string]: Filter[keyof Filter];
}

type Possibles = 'possibleOrganizations' | 'possibleFarms' | 'possiblePlans' | 'possibleCropTypes' | 'possibleFields'

type IDs = 'organizationIds' | 'farmIds' | 'planIds' | 'cropTypeIds' | 'fieldIds'

const myFilter:Filter = {
  cropTypeIds: [2,3,4,7,9,21,33,54],
  farmIds: [1,2,3,4],
  fieldIds: [3,6,9,4,2,66,99,22],
  serviceProviderId: 1,
  organizationIds: [6,3,8,2],
  planIds: [7,12],
  possibleFields: [
    {id: 3, name: 'FieldNo3'},
    {id: 6, name: 'FieldNo6'},
    {id: 9, name: 'FieldNo9'},
    {id: 4, name: 'FieldNo4'},
    {id: 2, name: 'FieldNo2'},
    {id: 66, name: 'FieldNo66'},
    {id: 99, name: 'FieldNo99'},
    {id: 22, name: 'FieldNo22'}
  ],
  possibleFarms: [
    {id: 13, name: 'FarmNo13'},
    {id: 56, name: 'FarmNo56'},
    {id: 43, name: 'FarmNo43'},
    {id: 87, name: 'FarmNo87'},
    {id: 52, name: 'FarmNo52'}
  ],
  possibleOrganizations: [
    {id: 2, name: 'OrgNo2', organizationTypeId: 1},
    {id: 3, name: 'OrgNo3', organizationTypeId: 1},
    {id: 6, name: 'OrgNo6', organizationTypeId: 2},
    {id: 8, name: 'OrgNo8', organizationTypeId: 1},
    {id: 12, name: 'OrgNo12', organizationTypeId: 2},
    {id: 32, name: 'OrgNo32', organizationTypeId: 1},
    {id: 54, name: 'OrgNo54', organizationTypeId: 3}
  ],
  possibleCropTypes: [
    {id: 2, name: 'CropTypeNo2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'CropTypeNo3'},
    {id: 4, name: 'CropTypeNo4'},
    {id: 7, name: 'CropTypeNo7'},
    {id: 9, name: 'CropTypeNo9'},
    {id: 21, name: 'CropTypeNo21'},
    {id: 33, name: 'CropTypeNo33'},
    {id: 54, name: 'CropTypeNo54'}
  ],
  possiblePlans: [
    {id: 7, name: 'PlanNo2'},
    {id: 12, name: 'PlanNo12'},
    {id: 32, name: 'PlanNo32'},
    {id: 56, name: 'PlanNo56'}
  ],
  userId: 22
}

const filterNameLookup:{ [key:Possibles]:IDs } = {
  possibleOrganizations: 'organizationIds',
  possibleFarms: 'farmIds',
  possiblePlans: 'planIds',
  possibleCropTypes: 'cropTypeIds',
  possibleFields: 'fieldIds'
}

const resetFilter = () => {
  const possibleKeys = Object.keys(filterNameLookup)
  possibleKeys.forEach((key) => {
    if (myFilter[key].length === myFilter[filterNameLookup[key]].length) {
      myFilter[filterNameLookup[key]].length = 0
    }
  })
}
```

How do I ensure that only the arrays in MyFilter are read in a type-safe way? I currently get typescript error:

```
TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number | boolean | number[] | FilterItem[] | OrganizationFilterItem[]'.
  Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Expected result after running 'resetFilter()' would be (without typescript errors):

```js
myFilter = {
  cropTypeIds: [],
  farmIds: [1,2,3,4],
  fieldIds: [],
  serviceProviderId: 1,
  organizationIds: [6,3,8,2],
  planIds: [7,12],
  possibleFields: [3,6,9,4,2,66,99,22],
  possibleFarms: [13,56,43,87,52],
  possibleOrganizations: [2,3,6,8,12,32,54],
  possibleCropTypes: [2,3,4,7,9,21,33,54],
  possiblePlans: [7,12,32,56,98],
  userId: 22
}
```

Thanks very much for taking a look ;)

Comment: IF you copy and paste your code in TS playground, you will see that some of your typing are incorrect. Fo example: possibleFields, possibleFarms.
Could you please fix it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. My apologies, I have corrected the data for possibleFarms and possibleOrganizations - in typescript playground I now only see the issues I can not overcome within the resetFilter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEt's start with `Filter` interface.

```js
interface Filter {
  serviceProviderId: number;
  farmIds: number[];
  organizationIds: number[];
  userId: number;
  possibleFields: FilterItem[];
  possibleFarms: FilterItem[];
  cropTypeIds: number[];
  planIds: number[];
  possibleOrganizations: OrganizationFilterItem[];
  possibleCropTypes: FilterItem[];
  possiblePlans: FilterItem[];
  fieldIds: number[];
  [key: string]: Filter[keyof Filter]; // this is wrong
}
```

There is no sense to use `[key: string]: Filter[keyof Filter]`? Are you expect dublicated properties ? What shape of object are you expect?

```js
interface Filter {
  fieldIds: number[];
  fieldIds: number[];
  [key: string]: Filter[keyof Filter]; // properties are dublicated because of index
}
```

So, I removed `[key: string]: Filterp[keyof Filter]`

**This is my solution:**

```js
interface FilterItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface OrganizationFilterItem extends FilterItem {
  organizationTypeId: number;
}

interface Filter {
  serviceProviderId: number;
  farmIds: number[];
  organizationIds: number[];
  userId: number;
  possibleFields: FilterItem[];
  possibleFarms: FilterItem[];
  cropTypeIds: number[];
  planIds: number[];
  possibleOrganizations: OrganizationFilterItem[];
  possibleCropTypes: FilterItem[];
  possiblePlans: FilterItem[];
  fieldIds: number[];
  // [key: string]: Filter[keyof Filter];
}


type IDs = 'organizationIds' | 'farmIds' | 'planIds' | 'cropTypeIds' | 'fieldIds'

const myFilter: Filter = {
  cropTypeIds: [2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 21, 33, 54],
  farmIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  fieldIds: [3, 6, 9, 4, 2, 66, 99, 22],
  serviceProviderId: 1,
  organizationIds: [6, 3, 8, 2],
  planIds: [7, 12],
  possibleFields: [
    { id: 3, name: 'FieldNo3' },
    { id: 6, name: 'FieldNo6' },
    { id: 9, name: 'FieldNo9' },
    { id: 4, name: 'FieldNo4' },
    { id: 2, name: 'FieldNo2' },
    { id: 66, name: 'FieldNo66' },
    { id: 99, name: 'FieldNo99' },
    { id: 22, name: 'FieldNo22' }
  ],
  possibleFarms: [
    { id: 13, name: 'FarmNo13' },
    { id: 56, name: 'FarmNo56' },
    { id: 43, name: 'FarmNo43' },
    { id: 87, name: 'FarmNo87' },
    { id: 52, name: 'FarmNo52' }
  ],
  possibleOrganizations: [
    { id: 2, name: 'OrgNo2', organizationTypeId: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'OrgNo3', organizationTypeId: 1 },
    { id: 6, name: 'OrgNo6', organizationTypeId: 2 },
    { id: 8, name: 'OrgNo8', organizationTypeId: 1 },
    { id: 12, name: 'OrgNo12', organizationTypeId: 2 },
    { id: 32, name: 'OrgNo32', organizationTypeId: 1 },
    { id: 54, name: 'OrgNo54', organizationTypeId: 3 }
  ],
  possibleCropTypes: [
    { id: 2, name: 'CropTypeNo2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'CropTypeNo3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'CropTypeNo4' },
    { id: 7, name: 'CropTypeNo7' },
    { id: 9, name: 'CropTypeNo9' },
    { id: 21, name: 'CropTypeNo21' },
    { id: 33, name: 'CropTypeNo33' },
    { id: 54, name: 'CropTypeNo54' }
  ],
  possiblePlans: [
    { id: 7, name: 'PlanNo2' },
    { id: 12, name: 'PlanNo12' },
    { id: 32, name: 'PlanNo32' },
    { id: 56, name: 'PlanNo56' }
  ],
  userId: 22
}

type Possibles = 'possibleOrganizations' | 'possibleFarms' | 'possiblePlans' | 'possibleCropTypes' | 'possibleFields'


const filterNameLookup: Record<Possibles, IDs> = {
  possibleOrganizations: 'organizationIds',
  possibleFarms: 'farmIds',
  possiblePlans: 'planIds',
  possibleCropTypes: 'cropTypeIds',
  possibleFields: 'fieldIds'
}

const keys = <T,>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>

const resetFilter = (possibleKeys: Possibles[]) => {
  //  const possibleKeys = Object.keys(filterNameLookup)
  possibleKeys.forEach((key) => {
    if (myFilter[key].length === myFilter[filterNameLookup[key]].length) {
      myFilter[filterNameLookup[key]].length = 0
    }
  })
}

const result = resetFilter(keys(filterNameLookup)) // expected result
```

Object.keys always will return `string[]` instead of `(keyof T)[]` this is by design, so we should help TS to figure out that we need array of keys instead just array of any strings

Please keep in mind, any time you want to get indexed property in TS, make sure TS understand that it is possible